# How to use IdentityDbContext with SQLite database in EF Core?

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, migration

I cannot use IdentityDbContext with SQLite in EF Core because I am unable to apply migrations. I have this error:

> SQLite does not support this migration operation
>   ('AddForeignKeyOperation').

I know only that I have to rewrite migration manually (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations). But how? My db context class is just empty class inheriting after IdentityDbContext

Answer (score 0):

i have this issue, just remove all migration and add new one of it

Remove-Migration oldmigration

Add-Migration NewMigration